# How to create a test and train dataset in R by specifying the range in the data set instead of using set.seed() function and probability?

Tags: r, validation, training-data, seed

I am a noob at programming, sorry if this is a silly question.

My supervisor doesn't seem to trust set.seed() function in r as every number will yield a different output (with different test and train sets). Thus she asked me to specify the range for my training and test dataset.

I am conducting a Binary logistic regression model in R with a sample size of 1790. There are 8 independent variables in my model. I want to do a 70/30 split for train and test data. I did it using these lines of code the first time:

```
RLV <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)

set.seed(123)
index <- sample(2, nrow(RLV), replace = T, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
train <- RLV[index == 1,]
test <- RLV[index == 2,]
```

But if I change 123 into say 1234, the output is similar but not exactly the previous one (and yes I know that's the point).
But according to my supervisor, she wants me to **train** using the data obtained in Day 1 and Day 2 and **test(validate)** using the data of Day 3 (That was my initial plan as well).

Thus after intense brainstorming I came up with these lines of code...

```
RLV <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)

train <- RLV[1:1253,]
test <- RLV[1254:1790,]
head(test)
```

I want all the rows from **1 to 1253** (all columns too) in my **train** dataset and from **1254 to 1790** in my **test(validation)** dataset.

I checked using the head function and it does seem to work. But I am on the fence here. Can someone please clarify how this works? Or please if its even right (lol). I just want to complete this project without any hassle.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said: It does work. `head()` shows you the first six rows of a dataframe. So you should get rows 1254, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, and 1259 from your 'test set' after `head(test)`.

It works because if you index a dataframe with `[,]`, everything before the comma specifies *row restrictions* and everything after the comma specifies *column restrictions*. You indexed by row number. It would also be possible to index by a logical vector. For example, `RLV[RLV$Day %in% 1:2,]` would give you all cases from `RLV` where (the hypothetical) column `Day` holds the value 1 or 2.

If this doesn't answer your question(s), please specify what you mean by "how this works" and "if it's even right" ;)

Comment: Wow ... Thanks a lot for the reply. Will definitely try that

Comment: The head() function showed exactly the rows you mentioned above. I guess it works lol. Thanks for the explanation.